# Extract remaining lines not under polygon

Tags: qgis

I have a lines layer that I want to clip using a polygon and then determine how much line km I have remaining.

Using the clip process I can only keep the lines under the polygon... How can I clip the lines under the polygon and make a shapefile of the remaining lines?

I'm using QGIS 3.16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "[Difference](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference)" tool in Vector Overlay should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This did exactly what I needed.